# This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit. But the final version is mine!

Tags: support

I understand what the error message means.

But when I looked at my [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16134452) and the [final version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43992683/revisions), I found that they match, however, the edit credits went to the original post creator.

Why was my edit rejected?

**Update**

There is one difference between the two edits.

Comment: I'm not sure why yours was rejected, but could you tell me why you would change honour to honor? As far as I know there isn't a rule that states all communication should be in American English, not British English, or is there?

Comment: This is an old issue that I don't have a satisfactory answr for. Essentially your edit was merged with the OP's subsequent edit: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141867/suggested-edit-overwritten-by-op-edit

Answer (score -1):

The final version is not yours. If you compare the two edits you can see they are the same except for one detail:

`(app) side` (OP) vs `(app) site` (YOU)

You did not change that, thus it's conflicting as you did the same minus that.

Comment: So, why my edit was merged into the OP edit?

Comment: I just compared the links you provided. I don't see it saying it was merged

Comment: Also you said you found that they match... They don't so...

Comment: You mean that the OP has made an edit to the post that exactly fixed the same mistakes? He even changed 'honour' to 'honor'? Ok!

Comment: Or he just edited your proposed edit. Point still is, you say the edits are the same, they are not.

Comment: *"Or he just edited your proposed edit"* The review result would be different.

Comment: @Tom ...the full reason has already been given by psubsee2003 (this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141867/suggested-edit-overwritten-by-op-edit). And this answer just tells OP what I see. He says the same edit, I say (see) not.

Comment: I'm not talking about what OP see and what you see. I've quoted a part of your comment and commented that, nothing else.

Comment: @Tom I understand, I'm just saying that even though *"Or he just edited your proposed edit"* is a wrong statement, its not what I'm basing my answer on :).