# Edit rejected by community but applied

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I made an edit today and formatted some code and fixed some grammar. It was very specific and I don't think anyone can make the exact same edit. Post in question (Revision #2): [VBA (Widows Forms) Loop and Time Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904251/vba-widows-forms-loop-and-time-delay) Rejected edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17156969

The two pictures below, one is from my rejected edit and one is from the question's edit history.

[image]

[image]

I checked the post and the edit was applied by another user (not the original poster), and mine was rejected. Something similar happens to me all the time, where a user accepts my edit and then edits more, I believe it's an option called `Accept and Edit`, but this is not what happened here. I'm wondering what happened here?

EDIT

I've checked [This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit. But the final version is mine!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349233/this-edit-conflicted-with-a-subsequent-edit-but-the-final-version-is-mine) and [Edit rejected but question is updated with my edit: This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294766/edit-rejected-but-question-is-updated-with-my-edit-this-edit-conflicted-with-a) but in those cases the edits seemed to be different between the users.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17156969: another edit was submitted in the meantime.

Comment: In this case, as you can see from [the suggested edit itself](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17156969), it *was* a conflict with a subsequent edit that caused your edit to be rejected. The Community user (a bot with moderator privileges) handles these automatic rejections. This is exactly the same case as [This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit. But the final version is mine!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349233), and as described [here on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141872): your edits were merged so they look the same.

Comment: Unlikely as it sounds, it looks like someone else submitted the exact same edit at around the same time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters exactly the same?

Comment: @tima: the diff on [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45904251/revisions), and [your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17156969) look the same to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, those are the two pictures in this post. Why does it seem like another user made the edit? Shouldn't it be the `Community` if the edit was merged.

Comment: @tima: I don't know; never saw a post get merged like that before.

Comment: Isn't *Widows forms* capturing the state of that technology nicely?

Comment: Hmm, it is the part of the 4.7 update that got the most internal changes.  Looks like it will easily outlast jQuery.  Hey, poking fun at mature technology is everybody's pastime.

Comment: *I don't think anyone can make the exact same edit.* It makes sense that someone else would make most of the same changes because nearly all of them are grammar and formatting changes. What doesn't make sense is that they also made the exact same mistakes: Leaving in the noise at the beginning, missing the last 'i' at the end. That's much weirder to me than them correcting the same problems.